When a struct member is a struct, its alignment and size are different from native types?
I found an interesting phenomenon when programming in C: when a member of a structure is a structure, the alignment requirement of this structure member is the size of its largest member. I didn't find relevant content in the C standard (if I am blind, please remind me), but mainstream compilers all implement it this way.
Let's look at the following code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

struct W {
    uint8_t hi;
    uint8_t lo;
};

struct S1 {
    uint8_t b1;
    uint16_t w1;
};

struct S2 {
    uint8_t b1;
    struct W w1;
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    printf("sizeof(uint16_t) : %zu\n", sizeof(uint16_t));
    printf("sizeof(struct W) : %zu\n", sizeof(struct W));
    printf("sizeof(struct S1): %zu\n", sizeof(struct S1));
    printf("sizeof(struct S2): %zu\n", sizeof(struct S2));

    printf("================================================\n");

    struct S1 s1 = { 0 };
    printf("&s1      : %p\n", &s1);
    printf("&s1.b1   : %p\n", &s1.b1);
    printf("&s1.w1   : %p\n", &s1.w1);

    struct S2 s2 = { 0 };
    printf("&s2      : %p\n", &s2);
    printf("&s2.b1   : %p\n", &s2.b1);
    printf("&s2.w1   : %p\n", &s2.w1);
    printf("&s2.w1.hi: %p\n", &s2.w1.hi);
    printf("&s2.w1.lo: %p\n", &s2.w1.lo);
}

The output is as follows:
sizeof(uint16_t) : 2
sizeof(struct W) : 2
sizeof(struct S1): 4
sizeof(struct S2): 3
================================================
&s1      : 0000003D4C97FCB4
&s1.b1   : 0000003D4C97FCB4
&s1.w1   : 0000003D4C97FCB6
&s2      : 0000003D4C97FCD4
&s2.b1   : 0000003D4C97FCD4
&s2.w1   : 0000003D4C97FCD5
&s2.w1.hi: 0000003D4C97FCD5
&s2.w1.lo: 0000003D4C97FCD6

When the size of member w1 is 2 bytes, why is sizeof(struct S2) smaller than sizeof(struct S1)? And struct S1 is 2-byte aligned but struct S2 is 1-byte aligned.
This code has been run on both MSVC and GCC with consistent results.

Just read this article.

Your code does not really show the premise, does it? The only struct used as a member here, W, has only bytes as members, hence no alignment requirements or even desires. I bet you the compiler makes sure of the necessary or desirable (for speed) alignments for structs if they are members as well as when they are not. Note that member alignment may change on architectures supporting unaligned access when you optimize for size or use a #pragma pack.

See godbolt: With #pragma pack(1), struct S1 fits in 3 bytes.

@Peter I know that there are compiler-specific ways to control the layout of the structure, but I would prefer to use the way defined by the C standard.

@CarlHR, This is a nice article.

Well, since the layout is compiler specific it is not surprising that the options are compiler specific -- and aren't they all? The standard does not even specify compilers (it mentions it only in examples and footnotes), let a lone their options. That said, pragma pack was added to gcc (and then taken over by clang) for compatibility with MSVC, so that it is not that compiler specific ;-).

@Peter-ReinstateMonica C11's _Alignas seems to be the general approach.

None of this is guaranteed by the C standard, but in this particular case, the alignment requirements of the struct appears to be the alignment of the member with the largest alignment. A uint16_t has 2-byte alignment on your system, so when you place one after a uint8_t, the compiler adds a 1-byte padding to make sure the uint16_t is properly aligned, because some systems do not support dereferencing addresses to types that are not a multiple of the alignment requirement of the type.
When you only have a struct with more uint8_t, those members can be packed immediately after the uint8_t member because there are no members whose alignment requirements are violated.
Size is not alignment. Size is how much memory the type takes up, and alignment is multiple by which an address must be. If you have a pointer 4 byte integer and the pointer is not divisible by 4, that would be bad news on some systems.
Structures are collections of other types, so in theory, only the alignment requirements of their individual members need to apply, thus having an alignment smaller than their size.

Thanks for your answer.
The C standard does not specify this, so I should not use this feature to control the layout of the structure. Otherwise, my code will not work properly when the compiler implementation changes in the future.
So under the current C standard, if I want to control the layout of the structure, I can only use compiler-specific methods?

@dsyx In C, you could in theory manually allocate a block of memory and store data in at fixed offsets, but that would be very unwieldy, but there is no Standard way to manipulate the layout of a struct. One must use compiler-specific methods, yes.

Yes, the most direct way is to open a memory block and then define a bunch of macros to represent the index. Using structures to represent layout is more maintenance-friendly, but the current C standard does not allow programmers to ensure that the layout of the structure is what they expect. Programmers can only make guarantees through compiler-specific methods, but this will limit the cross-platform capabilities of the code.

@dsyx - Why do you feel a need to manually affect the cross-platform layout? Perhaps you should trust each compiler to select a good layout for its platform? There is almost never a way to be 100% portable, as already using uint8_t gets you down below 99%, by excluding platforms without an 8 bit byte.

@BoP For example, if you need to save an object to a file, and want the layout to be consistent so you can transfer the file to other computers and the results to be expected. I know there are other issues like big/little endian but lack of control over structure layout just adds one more issue.

@BoP Because the manual layout instructions vary from compiler to compiler, and some compilers may not even support manual layout.

@dsyx Well, you can limit compiler dependencies by using explicitly-sized types (which you are already doing). You can control the remaining dependencies by using compiler specific methods (pragma pack) that are widely supported though; and you can assert that a port leads to the expected layout by asserting sizes at compile time and offsets (I think only at run time).

@Peter-ReinstateMonica Why only at runtime? sizeof is a compile time operator for sure, and so is the offsetof macro, as far as I can tell. While sizeof cannot be used in a #if, sizeof can be used in _Static_assert.

The C requirement is just this (C17 6.7.2.1):

Each non-bit-field member of a structure or union object is aligned in an implementation-defined manner appropriate to its type.

This means that each member is aligned based on its own type, but the compiler is free to do so as it pleases. And the compiler may add any number of padding bytes anywhere in the struct except at the very beginning.
The compiler is however required to allocate the members in a strict order where the first one is always on the lowest address (also from 6.7.2.1):

a structure is a type consisting of a sequence of members, whose storage is
allocated in an ordered sequence

This requirement means that the compiler is unable to re-order the struct members to suit alignment better. The programmer is in charge of it.
In case of S1 the member b1 does not have an alignment requirement but w1 does. Therefore a padding byte has to be appended after b1 simply because b1 has size 1 which would force the next member in the struct to an odd address.
However, swapping the order of the members in this case wouldn't improve the situation, since the beginning of each struct will have to start at an alignment appropriate for the largest alignement requirement of a member of the struct. Since the compiler must make it possible for an array of structs to be allocated etc.
So if we swapped the order of b1 and w1 we'd merely move the padding bytes that was placed between the members to the end instead.

S2 is more like directly introducing the members of the substructure directly into the parent structure instead of treating the substructure as a type.

Dynamic allocation is another reason, besides arrays, for middle-padding (on the stack, the compiler could simply allocate S1s at odd addresses, but malloc() must return aligned memory).

@Peter-ReinstateMonica malloc is another story since it uses something called "fundamental alignment requirement", not quite the same thing as alignment based on a certain type. Hence the need for the aligned_alloc function, when you need a different alignment than the fundamental one.


I found an interesting phenomenon when programming in C: when a member of a structure is a structure, the alignment requirement of this structure member is the size of its largest member.

This is not generally true. It is generally the member with the strictest alignment requirement, not the largest size, that governs the structure’s alignment requirement. Two simple examples are:

struct { char x[11]; }. Here, the largest member is 11 bytes, but the alignment requirement of this structure will normally be one byte, as the alignment requirement of the member is just one byte. In a structure that contains another structure, the contained structure could be quite large, but only its alignment requirement, not its size, will be used to affect the alignment requirement of the containing structure.
struct { uint64_t x; }. Consider a C implementation in which the hardware provides only 32-bit arithmetic instructions and the compiler supports 64-bit integer types by using multiple instructions. The compiler will store a uint64_t by storing two 32-bit integers. The hardware has only a four-byte alignment requirement, so the compiler has no need to align x to a multiple of eight bytes. Since x is effectively two four-byte items, it does not matter whether it is stored on an eight-byte boundary or not. The size of x will be eight bytes, but its alignment requirement will be four bytes, and so will that have the structure.

The C standard’s specifications require that the alignment requirement of a structure be at least as strict as the strictest alignment of its members. This is a logical necessity since alignment each member requires aligning the structure. Most C implementations will not use any stricter alignment requirement than that since there is normally no benefit in it.
This answer has the algorithm that is commonly used to lay out structures.

When the size of member w1 is 2 bytes, why is sizeof(struct S2) smaller than sizeof(struct S1)? And struct S1 is 2-byte aligned but struct S2 is 1-byte aligned.

The members of struct S2 have only one-byte alignment requirements: b1 is a uint8_t with a one-byte alignment requirement, and w1 is a struct W, which consists of two one-byte members each with a one-byte alignment requirement. So the alignment requirement of struct S2 is one byte, and its three bytes do not require any padding.
In struct S1, its w1 member has a two-byte alignment requirement. Because w1 is preceded by a single one-byte member, a byte of padding must be inserted to give w1 a two-byte alignment. This makes the total structure size four bytes, and the structure has a two-byte alignment requirement because that is the strictest alignment requirement of its members.
You can see the alignment requirement of a type by printing _Alignof (type) with %zu instead of printing the address of an object of that type. For example, printf("%zu\n", _Alignof (struct S1)); will print “2” even if some object of that type might happen to receive an address that is a multiple of eight bytes.

The alignment requirement of a substructure is the maximum alignment requirement of the substructure's members, not the substructure itself.

@dsyx: I do not see what point you are trying to make. The text in this answer says that the alignment requirement of a substructure (“the contained structure”) is used in determining the alignment requirement of the containing structure (it factors into it the same way other members do—the strictest alignment requirement of the members becomes the requirement of the containing structure). How the substructure’s alignment requirement was determined is irrelevant; its alignment requirement is what it is.
